# Forbid move semantic in universal references

Tags: c++, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Universal references can bind to both rvalue or lvalue references. With `std::forward` one can perfectly forward arguments, including move references. Is it possible to exclude move semantic?

To be more concrete, let me consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <class FType, typename T>
void f(FType&& g, T&& v)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(v));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    // Case 1
    f([](std::vector<int> x) { x.push_back(3); }, v);
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4d06eac40907b64).

I would like the function `f` to forward to `g` a `const std::vector<int>&` or `std::vector<int>&`, but not a `std::vector<int>&&`.
In the above code, `g` receives a copy of a vector (because of its signature), so `v` is untouched by `f`.

Had I written

```
    // Case 2
    f([](std::vector<int>& x) { x.push_back(3); }, v);
```

then `v` would be increased in size by 1.

On the other hand, with the above code for `f` I could also do

```
    // Case 3
    f([](std::vector<int> x) { x.push_back(3); }, std::move(v));
```

In this case `v` is moved to a temporary argument `x`, and so after `f` it is in an undefined state (tipically it will have 0 size).
This third case is the case I would like to avoid, that is, I would like the user of `f` to not be able to do a move.

Knowing that `std::move` does not guarantee that a move is actually done, a solution seems to be:

```
template <class FType, typename T>
void f(FType&& g, T&& v)
{
    g(v);
}
```

This way, in the case 3 the lambda function receive a temporary copy.
Trying the various combinations, it appears that `g` always receive a const or non-const reference, but not a moving one, as I want.

Is this a correct solution, or are there some pitfalls?

Comment: By "moving reference" you mean rvalue references? If you do not forward, `f::v` is always an lvalue. So you want Case 1 and 3 to be identical? What about just `f(FType&& g, T& v)`, Case 3 won't compile, is that what you want?